# How can I figure out what code was just run?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, events, visual-studio-2012

Im using VS2012 to analyze a large project that I havent seen before. Im trying to figure out what happens when I click a button, but I dont know where the code for the event is. Is there any way I can get VS to tell me what code was recently run? Or perhaps a way to see what event handlers are associated with a UI element?

Comment: Can't you find at any point during that button's execution what is being done? For example if it reads a file at some point, can you find where that is done? Place a breakpoint there and go back up the callstack to see what came before it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Nope, not yet. Giant code base, very little clue what it does. Eventually Ill be able to do that, but I dont know where to start looking right now, and it would be much faster if VS could tell me instead of me having to parse through volumes of code.

Comment: I think you can just pause execution then. Execute the application in debug mode and after you clicked the button, press the pause symbol (or use `ctrl` + `alt` + `break` or *Debug* -> *Break All*). Now you can inspect the callstack.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Code executes WAY too fast for me to do that.

Comment: Break it before you press the button. Then click the button (UI should still be functional). Then take a few steps. This _might_ work

Comment: @Vlad274 Nope, didnt work. When I stepped over/into it just continued. Im guessing because its handled on another thread.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running (Specifically are you running Ultimate where you could use IntlliTrace). Also do you know where the button is defined? That would be a good starting point

Comment: What is the project set up like? If we knew the design pattern, we might be able to point to a location where the code could be. For example, have you check the .xaml.cs file associated with the page the button is on?

Comment: @EdChapel Doesnt seem to be either... I'm poking around now, trying to figure it out

Comment: @Vlad274 Still trying to figure it out myself

Comment: why don't you just search for assigments to the onclick event?

Comment: What kind of application is it?  Winforms, webforms, mvc, spa?

Comment: may be DotCover (http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) can help you ("Highlighting for covered and uncovered code in Visual Studio.").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension (developed by me, 30-day trial) to list all methods executed after you click on a button.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a code profiling tool.  Normally used to profile performance, it will definitely show you each and every routine hit in your codebase during a particular action.

Some of the more popular ones are [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and RedGate's [ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand&utm_campaign=ANTSPerformanceProfiler&gclid=CIqRjsajysACFehj7AodggcA1Q).  I think the more expensive versions of Visual Studio.NET also have some profiling built in.  Depending on if your code is all managed, and what the execution environment is like (Windows, web, etc.) your mileage may vary.

Edit: In my copy of VS.NET 2013 Pro, I just found the profiler under Analyze -> Profiler.